# I found this ship... can I steal it?

Tags: starfield

I was walking along in this planet, looking for the next rock to destroy when I heard a strange "ship entering the atmosphere" sound that I haven't heard before. I looked around but I could see a very dimly lit ship quietly landing. I went up to check it out and thought, "Nice! I want it!"

[image]
*Oooh, a Starborn Guardian*

If I climb up the wing, there's apparently a door, but it's inaccessible now. Maybe I'll need to find a different ship and it *would* be available, hopefully.

[image]
*The door*

I don't see anyone around... can I steal it?

Comment: It appears the crew is actually patrolling around the area, I just didn't notice them earlier. But I took them out to destruction and it didn't change my situation.

Comment: Found this reddit post but I'm not sure what to make of it https://www.reddit.com/r/Starfield/comments/169hhdp/is_a_starborn_guardian_supposed_to_be_inaccessible/

Comment: So at least according to that thread, I just missed my window of opportunity. Perhaps a bug to be able to get it since you can only enter the moment the crew is exiting. I was too far to even attempt that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can steal it. However, there's *severely* limited time window to steal the ship.

That ship is called **[Starborn Guardian](https://starfield.fandom.com/wiki/Starborn_Guardian)**, a prize for:

> Entering NG+. Despite that ship is being prize for ng+, it can be stolen if you find the ship in first playthrough, if you're lightning fast.

The ship is guarded by Starborn soldiers, but don't bother fighting them. Instead, just run in to the ship, and take control of it. If you try to fight the Starborn soldiers, they would get out of the ship before you could enter, and they'll lock the door, thus making door inaccessible. After you've stolen the ship, take the ship to technician and register it (I don't remember exact cost but it costed me 8000 ish credit or so), boom! the ship is now yours.

Don't worry about generator class, it's A so anyone can take control of that.

(These are based on my experience but I've also found a [website](https://www.starfielddb.com/ships/starborn-guardian/) that has its stats and a guide for stealing)

Comment: Just a side note: Is it even worthwhile to capture and later sell ships? So far, I never got a big profit, even if I sell all the little things like pens, paper and sukulents.

Comment: I'd say it's worth if you don't register, not worth if you register. I personally just go smuggling with commerce or mission boards.

Comment: @PeterCo Personally I'd still sell em, despite the registration fees. One thing I noticed is that the registration doesn't dip into the vendor's credits. So if you're constantly selling things and the vendors can't afford it, you'll be glad to know that ship sellers can afford your unregistered ships.